# How can import jQuery UI using ES6 syntax and browserify?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, ecmascript-6

I am trying to import JQuery and JQuery into a project using ES6 syntax using Babel and Browserify to package the code. From what I have been able to figure out the problem is that JQuery UI expects jQuery to be defined as a global variable. I tried setting the global variable after importing jQuery and before importing JQuery UI like this:

```
import { default as $, default as jQuery} from 'jquery';

wiindow.jQuery = jQuery;
window.$ = $;

import 'jquery-ui';
```

but it seems browserify puts all imports at the top of the file, so the globals are defined too late. I understand that webpack provides a way to define globals but is there a workaround for browserify?

Comment: If you found a jQuery version that works as a ES6 module, why isn't there one for jQuery-UI as well? It really should declare its own dependency on jQuery.

Comment: Well that's what you think. I installed both JQuery and JQuery-UI using npm. I am kinda new to JS development but from my research, JQuery is designed to work with the node module system which is evidently what browserify emulates whilst JQuery-UI is designed to work with the AMD module standard. You would think the projects would coordinate. I have been able to get var $ = global.$ = require('jquery') to work which is not terrible but it's not quite what I want. Am going to look into something called deamdify. Can't help thinking this stuff is harder than it should be.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = import $ from "jquery";
```

or

```
import { default as $, default as jQuery} from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = windows.$ = jQuery;
```

Comment: The first is a syntax error, the second one exactly the non-working version that the OP already has.